# global static Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, global-variables

I am writing a C# test code and new in it. Kind of confused and need help. This is a skeletal code and not entire code. I am looking for solution where I can keep test_dict keys IP and host intact along different methods and only update NET_MSG value.

```
public partial testclass
{
    IDictionary<string, string> test_dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
    String ping_msg;

    private void test1()
    {
       test_dict = develop.AddPing(ping_msg);
    }
```

Every time I add a new message in `test_dict["NET_MSG"]` in below methods, and print `test_dict`, I get only one key in `test_dict` which is `test_dict["NET_MSG"]` and I do not see IP address and host.

I am confused since I am using a global dictionary variable and once the `test_dict` is called from `test1()`, `test_dict` would be having all three keys correct, `NET_MSG`, `IP`, and `HOST`. Then why everytime if I change the value of only `NET_MSG` key inside `call_test` methods I lose other two keys `IP` and `HOST`?

```
public void call_test1()
{
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message";
}

    public void call_test2()
{
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message 2";
}

    public void call_test3()
{
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message3";
}
```

In another file:

```
public static class develop
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> AddPing(String message)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> new_ping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        new_ping["NET_MSG"] = message;
        new_ping["IP"] = "192.168.111.111";
        new_ping["HOST"] = "some_host_name";
      
        return new_ping;
    } 
}
```

Please help me with this and any solution to the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you dropped a bunch of `;`

Comment: Are you sure `get_IP()` and `get_Host()` do return anything ? Further more how do you print the dictionary, what do you mean by this ?

Comment: Everytime you call `AddPing` you create new dictionary and return it. You lose other ips and host names

Comment: Why do you need method test1() ? It overrides test_dict. That could be the reason.

Comment: You are showing a lot of code that is unrelated - why?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to call the test messages? Are you creating a new instance of `testclass` before each call to `call_test1`, `call_test2` and `call_test3`? are you invoking `test1` before each call to `call_test1`, `call_test2` and `call_test3`?

Comment: @AdemCatamak, Thanks Can you suggest me how I can fix the over writing issue  in C#?

Comment: Some additional remarks: 1. Naming conventions: Please lookup C# naming conventions, e.g. when to use lower and upper case. Makes the code much more readable for other C# developers here on SO. 2. Don't use a dictionary to keep together different properties (net message, ip, hostname). Define a class for that. 3. Don't name anything "test" unless it's a unit test. 4. Why is testclass partial?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something about when a new dictionary is created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TrieQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest2
    {
        //1st new of Dictionary
        IDictionary<string, string> test_dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private String ping_msg;
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            test_dict = develop.AddPing(ping_msg);
            test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message";
        }
    }

    public static class develop
    {

        public static IDictionary<string, string> AddPing(String message)
        {
            //another new instance of the dictionary is created!!
            IDictionary<string, string> new_ping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            new_ping["NET_MSG"] = message;
            new_ping["IP"] = get_IP();
            new_ping["HOST"] = get_host();

            return new_ping;
        }

        private static string get_host()
        {
            return "host";
        }

        private static string get_IP()
        {
            return "ip";
        }
    }
}
```

I created this test code for you, so you understand what you are missing.

if you call the code inside the unit test, it will work for you.
however please notice the comments, I added, you are allocating a new dictionary twice, the first time the test is called and again inside your static class, so that means the if you write to the first allocated dictionary you will see an empty dictionary.

if you add test_dict into the watch list in debug mode you can also use make object Id command in order to see that you are creating new instance.

if you want to solve it you can pass the original dictionary as a parameter to the function.

```
 public static void AddPing(String message, IDictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    dict["NET_MSG"] = message;
    dict["IP"] = get_IP();
    dict["HOST"] = get_host();
}
```

Or please share more of your code, so I can follow your flow.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple console app just to show you how to modify the `test_dict` values:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Testclass();
        foo.test1();

        Display(foo);
        foo.call_test1();
        Display(foo);
        foo.call_test2();
        Display(foo);
        foo.call_test3();
        Display(foo);
        foo.call_test4();
        Display(foo);
    }

    private static void Display(Testclass foo)
    {
        foreach (var item in foo.test_dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value + item.Key);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public partial class Testclass
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> test_dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private String ping_msg;

    public void test1()
    {
        test_dict = Develop.AddPing(ping_msg);
    }

    // chnages only NET_MSG value, other test_dict fields stay untouched!!!
    public void call_test1()
    {
        test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message";
    }

    // chnages only NET_MSG value, other test_dict fields stay untouched!!!
    public void call_test2()
    {
        test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message 2";
    }

    // chnages only NET_MSG value, other test_dict fields stay untouched!!!
    public void call_test3()
    {
        test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message3";
    }

    // here you can change all the fields 
    public void call_test4()
    {
        test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "new net_msg value";
        test_dict["IP"] = "new ip value";
        test_dict["HOST"] = "new host value";
    }
}

public static class Develop
{

    public static string get_IP()
    {
        return "blah";
    }

    public static string get_host()
    {
        return "blah2";
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, string> AddPing(String message)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"NET_MSG", message},
            {"IP", get_IP()},
            {"HOST", get_host()}
        };
    }

}
```

As a result you should receive:

```
NET_MSG
blahIP
blah2HOST

Putting new messageNET_MSG
blahIP
blah2HOST

Putting new message 2NET_MSG
blahIP
blah2HOST

Putting new message3NET_MSG
blahIP
blah2HOST

new net_msg valueNET_MSG
new ip valueIP
new host valueHOST
```

Invoking `call_test1`, `call_test2` or `call_test3` you are changing only the NET_MSG. The other `test_dict` fields stay untouched. Hope it can help you. If you invoke the `call_test4`method you will change all the defined values of the `test_dict` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If the test class looks like this:

```
public partial testclass
{
  IDictionary<string, string> test_dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
  String ping_msg

  private void test1()
  {
   test_dict = develop.AddPing(ping_msg)
  }

  public void call_test1()
  {
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message";
  }

  public void call_test2()
  {
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message 2";
  }

  public void call_test3()
  {
    test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message3";
  }
}
```

The issue is that `test1()` is never being called to populate the initial dictionary so the initial dictionary is empty and the lines

```
test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message1";

test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message2";

test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message3";
```

are creating the key "NET_MSG" in the empty dictionary.

To populate and only change the NET_MSG add a call to `test1()` to set `test_dict` to the dictionary you want to use instead of an empty dictionary.

Also remember that if you are instantiating a new class each time, `test1()` must be called each time.

Example 1:

```
public void call_test1() {
  test1();
  test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message1";
}
```

Usage:

```
testclass test = new testclass(<ctor args>);
test.call_test1();
```

That will populate and then change `NET_MSG`

Example 2:

```
public void init() {
  test1();
}

public void call_test1() {
  test_dict["NET_MSG"] = "Putting new message1";
}
```

Usage:

```
testclass test = new testclass(<ctor args>);
test.init();
test.call_test1();
```

This is a little more explicit in identifying what is happening - that an init occurs so the data is initialized before the `call_*` methods are useful.

You can even:

```
testclass test = new testclass(<ctor args>);
test.init();
test.call_test1();
//Do something with the data
test.call_test2();
//Do something with the data
test.call_test3();
//Do something with the data
```

Then you init once and the call_* will use the same dictionary and only change the "NET_MSG" value.